# eclipse plugin > how to include a jar file programmaticaly

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

So..., I've made a plugin for Eclipse that generates a new java project and ads files from templates, etc... However the code in the /src directory is then uncompilable because I need to add a jar file I have to the libraries tab.

The project is already a Java project via:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject javaProject = org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.create(proj);
            org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClasspathEntry src = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(folder.getFullPath());
            IClasspathEntry jre = JavaCore.newContainerEntry(new Path(
                    org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.JRE_CONTAINER), new IAccessRule[0],
                    new IClasspathAttribute[] {
                        JavaCore.newClasspathAttribute("owner.project.facets", "java")
                    }, false);
            IClasspathEntry[] entries = new IClasspathEntry[] {
                    src, jre
            };
            javaProject.setRawClasspath(entries, proj.getFullPath().append("bin"), new NullProgressMonitor());
```

And now, basically, I need to do programmaticaly, what the button "Add Jars..." does.
[image]

Been struggling with this for a while...

Any code tips or a link to a tutorial that DOES EXACTLY THIS would be helpful. Please **no** links to generic Eclipse plugin tutorials :) as I've probably seen them all by now...

Thnx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it, not sure if your reqs are exaclty the same, but hope it helps in some way...

```
        IFile file = addJar(project, "/resources/myJar.jar", MY_JAR_TARGET_PATH, monitor); //$NON-NLS-1$
        newcpEntries.add(JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(file.getFullPath(), null, null, false));
        // .....
```

where addJar() looks something like this:

```
private static IFile addJar(IProject project, String srcPath, String targetPath, IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    URL srcURL = MyPlugin.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry(srcPath);
    IFile file = project.getFile(targetPath);
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = srcURL.openStream();
        file.create(is, true, monitor);
    } catch (CoreException e) {//...
              } catch (IOException e) {//...
              }
    finally {
        try {
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {}
    }
    return file;
}
```

Comment: the important (the most relevant) part > JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(file.getFullPath(), null, null, false)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you would do it through the eclipse API's, but all that jar config window does is write to your `project-name/.classpath` file which looks something like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <classpath>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="x-jars/lucene-fast-vector-highlighter-3.0.3-patch1822.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="x-jars/lucene-highlighter-3.0.3.jar"/>
```

So one option would be to have your setup code edit this file once the project has been created, but this is probably too much of hack for what you want though.